# rich:Autocomplete selection not working in IE 11 browser

Tags: richfaces

I am using Rich faces 4.2.1 version, I have I have used rich:autocomplete component, which is working fine in chrome and Firefox browsers. but when I use IE 11 browser I am unable to select the value from the auto complete. 
when I enter 3 character it is giving suggestion in popup but when I am trying to select the required value mouse pointer is not going to second value. is there any work around or hack code for this. to get it work on IE 11 browser?

Thanks in advance!
Kiran.

Comment: Are you using JqueryUI tooltip?

Comment: no I am not using Jquery. it is plain rich faces with JSF 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I have got an workaround, that is running the IE Browser in compatible mode, so I use

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />
```

tag in my start up page. by using this, rich: auto complete selection is working in IE11 also.
Thank You :)

Comment: Great, this can be helpful for others! You should accept your answer then ;-) (PS. Even so, I recommend you to migrate to jsf 2.2 and RF 4.5.X ;-))

Answer (score 0):

RichFaces has a lot of problems with their autocomplete (and select) component. Your problem is one of a few known issues. Check out:

1. [Cannot select option on IE11](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-13531) (this is your problem, in comments their mentioned that autocomplete was fixed as well)
2. [Autocomplete (...) can't select item by mouse](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-13640)
3. [rich:autocomplete needs two clicks to hide popup](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-12653)

So basically it looks like you have to upgrade RF version at least to 
4.3.6. (And since RF is being shutting down ([sad RichFaces future](https://developer.jboss.org/people/michpetrov/blog/2016/02/12/the-future-of-richfaces)) I highly recommend updating to the latest 4.5.X version because there will be no newest one)

Comment: instead of migrating to latest versions, is there any alternative work around to get it work?

Comment: @Kiran I don't know any. In most cases, when developers know about workaround they are writting about it. But you can ask on RF community forum or on their's JIRA